# Purpose of each files generated by angular-cli ng build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, production

I'm recently build my web app using angular-cli project. I wonder the meaning of each file generated after ng build include:

```
chunk.js
bundle.js
vender.js
inline.js
main.js 
polyfill.js
```